# Como obrigar threads a fazerem obrigatoriamente certas funçoes?

Tags: java

São acordadas 10 threads quando o Cliente faz a ligação ao servidor, quando o Cliente pede uma palavra, O servidor acorda estas threads e estas vao percorrer uma lista de tarefas.

O que queria que acontecesse: sempre que uma thread faz o scan() dessa palavra, retirasse essa tarefa da lista de maneira que quando a proxima corresse essa tarefa já nao estivesse na lista.

O que acontece: mais que uma thread começa a fazer o scan(), e fazem todas o scan() da primeira tarefa.

```
public  class ThreadSearcher extends Thread{
    private int x;

    public ThreadSearcher(int x){
        this.x=x;   

    }


    @Override
    public void run(){

        while(!interrupted()){

            System.out.println("Comecei a correr:" + x); 
            try {

                Tarefa t = getTarefas().get(0);
                scan(t);
                System.out.println("Sou a "+ this.x + " e fiz o scan de " + t.getStart() + "a" + t.getFinish());
                System.out.println("Sou a " + x + "antes de remover tinha " + tarefas.size());
                tarefas.remove(t);
                System.out.println("Sou a " + x + "depois de remover tinha " + tarefas.size());

                System.out.println("removi a" + t);



            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código da sua classe `Tarefa` e da classe onde você cria os seus `ThreadSearcher`, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é um problema de multithreading comum.

Basicamente você está compartilhando um `ArrayList` ou estrutura similar para as várias threads sem algum mecanismo de controle ou sincronização, portanto violando a consistência do seu programa.

Há várias formas de resolver isto. Vou citar duas.

### Sincronização manual

Sincronize as threads em relação à lista compartilhada para que somente uma thread possa modificar o objeto de cada vez.

Exemplo usando `synchronized`:

```
//recupere a lista
List<Tarefa> tarefas = getTarefas();
Tarefa t;
//a partir daqui, somente uma thread execute de cada vez
synchronized (tarefas) {
  //o método remove de uma lista retorna o elemento removido
  t = tarefas.remove(0);
}
//processa o elemento não compartilhado t fora do bloco sincronizado,
//caso contrário vai enfileirar cada elemento
scan(t)
```

#### Estrutura thread-safe

Existem alguns objetos em Java que permitem executar operações diretamente por várias threads de forma segura.

Por exemplo, o [`LinkedBlockingDeque` com seu método `poll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html#poll--) pode ser usado, então bastaria ter a sua lista de tarefas usando este tipo de objeto e suas threads assim:

```
//pega o primeiro item da lista, removendo-o
Tarefa t = getTarefas().poll();
//null significa que a lista estava fazia
if (t != null) {
    scan(t)
}
```

Além disso, o método `take()` pode ser usado se você quiser que a thread fique esperando a lista ter algum elemento. Ao invés de retornar `null` se a lista estiver vazia como no `poll()`, o método `take()` bloqueia a thread e fica esperando algum elemento ser adicionado.